# Unity 5.3.5f and SQL Server 2008 R2 : 'an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'

Tags: c#, sockets, sql-server-2008-r2, unity-game-engine

I have not yet received any feedback from this post in unity answer forums so I am posting here to broaden the visibility.

It appears this question has been asked a few times within the unity forums but no answers which have fixed my issues. I'm running unity 5.3.5f, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (was running SQL Server 2016 but read that the mono dll's are only compatible up to SQL Server 2008). I have the correct mono dll's in my assets folder properly referenced and built in my project. I'm running the database locally. I can get into it fine using SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio 2015 connects to it fine as well. I've completely dropped the firewall. Right now I'm just trying to get it to work within the unity ide. I have also verified incoming connections are allowed in SQL Server Management Studio and that tcp/ip is enabled in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Furthermore, examining the unity manual no documentation exists for database connections as far as I've seen.

My code:

```
public string RetrieveTestData(string query) { string sqlConnectionString = "Server=zzzz\\SQLEXPRESS2008;" + "Database=mydb;" + "User ID=sa;" + "Password=mypass;";

Debug.Log(sqlConnectionString);
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

try
{
    con.Open(); // error thrown here
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    var fubar = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    return fubar.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Log(ex.StackTrace);
    throw;
}

public void TestQuery()
{
     Debug.Log(RetrieveTestData("select top 1 * from dbo.Weapon"));
}
```

My error:

> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> Stack trace:
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom_nochecks_exc (System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags, System.Net.EndPoint& remote_end, Boolean throwOnError, System.Int32& error) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom_nochecks (System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags, System.Net.EndPoint& remote_end) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Net.EndPoint& remoteEP) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.Receive (System.Net.IPEndPoint& remoteEP) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection+SqlMonitorSocket.DiscoverTcpPort (Int32 timeoutSeconds) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.DiscoverTcpPortViaSqlMonitor (System.String ServerName, System.String InstanceName) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ParseDataSource (System.String theDataSource, System.Int32& thePort, System.String& theServerName) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x00000] in :0 at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection:Open () at Assets.Scripts.Data.DBBase.RetrieveTestData (System.String query) [0x00013] in C:\Development\Unity\twistedshadowsgame\TwistedShadows\Assets\Scripts\Data\DBBase.cs:23 UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) Assets.Scripts.Data.DBBase:RetrieveTestData(String) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/DBBase.cs:35) Assets.Scripts.Data.DBBase:TestQuery() (at Assets/Scripts/Data/DBBase.cs:43) Assets.Scripts.Data.DBBase:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/Data/DBBase.cs:48)

All help is greatly appreciated as this is the single item holding up all my progress. If I've not posted something or I need to post elsewhere please let me know.  I would rather not have to right a separate rest service for this.  I'm confident unity has the capabilities and from what I read it looks like it has been done by many others successfully.

thanks in advance! ryan

Answer (score 0):

Pretty "late to the game" on this, but I found the answer some time ago.  The proper design pattern is for writing a service that will make the database calls, and having unity make calls to that service.  For anyone else trying to pull data from a db to populate some object in unity, this is the preferred pattern.

thanks :)